# Conversion of Blob to UIImage from a Sqlite Database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiimage, blob

I saved an image using Coredata in my application. Then i imported the Sqlite file in another project and retrieved that Blob field and converted to NSData. Then i got a NULL value when trying to convert this NSData to UIImage.

```
NSData *data=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 1.0);
```

saved the above data by saving context

**To get back from Sqlite** ::

```
const char *sqlStatement = "select ID,NAME,IMAGE from CALL";
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 2) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 2)];
UIImage * showImage= [UIImage imageWithData: data];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are writing is correct.

**Difference I found in your code and some other code on internet is**:

You use: `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 1.0);`

They use: `UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.coffeeImage);`

Though this is not the correct solution of your question but though It may help you to investigate further in issue.